# SVN Update will not automatically resolve conflicts as expected

Tags: svn, version-control

I am writing a script that will first run SVN Update to get any new files that are in Source into my Working directory. If there are any conflicts, I want to keep what's in Source. The next part of the script updates Source with any new files that are in my Working directory. The part I am having trouble with (I believe) is the svn update command:

```
svn update --accept 'theirs-full'
```

When this step runs, it returns a friendly message stating that it is updating '.': at revision x. I am now under the assumption that any conflicts were resolved by keeping the files in Source. However, when I run the commit:

```
svn commit -m "updates made"
```

I receive the following error:

```
svn: E155015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155015: Aborting commit: 'c:\yada\yada\media\data.xml' remains in conflict
```

UPDATE:
The only way I can seem to get around this is by running:

```
svn resolve
Select: (r) mark resolved, (p) postpone, (q) quit resolution, (h) help:
```

And manually selecting 'r'. this is not an acceptable solution. I need this to all happen automatically.

Comment: What version of SVN?  Have you tried the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use Windows.  The `'` around the option are wrong. Here it looks like this:

```
C:\> svn up --accept 'theirs-full'
svn: E205000: ''theirs-full'' is not a valid --accept value
C:\> svn up --accept theirs-full
Updating '.':
```

I use subversion 1.8.4.